# Non deterministic Backbone Collection property assignment in console

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, console, backbone.js

I'm building a Backbone application and I'm observing some behaviour I can't place. Consider the following Collection:

```
window.Pictures = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Picture,
  url: 'latest.json',
  parse: function(response) {
    this.foobar = 1;
  },  
  fetchPage: function() {
    this.foobar = 2;
    return this;
  }
});
```

On a Chrome (or Firefox) console I've issued the following command:

```
> p = new Pictures(); p.fetch(); p.fetchPage();
> p.foobar
1
```

When I do:

```
> p = new Pictures(); p.fetch()
> p.fetchPage();
> p.foobar
2
```

I really don't understand this. Why is the first execution different from the second execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch) call is asynchronous because it involves an AJAX call to the server:

> **fetch** collection.fetch([options])
>   Fetch the default set of models for this collection from the server, resetting the collection when they arrive.

And `fetch` will call [`parse`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-parse):

> **parse** collection.parse(response)
>   **parse** is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are returned by the server, in `fetch`.

So `p.parse()` may be called before or after `p.fetchPage()` depending on timing issues that are beyond your control.

In the first case:

```
> p = new Pictures(); p.fetch(); p.fetchPage();
```

`fetchPage` is getting called before `fetch` gets its response from the server and gets around to calling `parse` so the calling sequence ends up like this this:

1. You call `p.fetch()`.
2. AJAX call is made.
3. You call `p.fetchPage()`.
4. AJAX response is received.
5. The AJAX success handler calls `p.parse()`.

In the second case:

```
> p = new Pictures(); p.fetch()
> p.fetchPage();
```

Enough time passes between the lines for the AJAX call to return before `p.fetchPage()` is called so things happen in the order expect purely by accident.

If you need things to happen in a certain order then you'll need to use the `success` (and possibly `error`) callback that `fetch` provides:

> The **options** hash takes `success` and `error` callbacks which will be passed `(collection, response)` as arguments.

So this should give you a consistent result of 2:

```
p = new Pictures();
p.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        collection.fetchPage();
        console.log(collection.foobar);
    }
});
```

Of course, if `fetchPage` involves an AJAX call then you'd have to add yet another layer of callbacks to get a consistent `foobar` value.

Comment: Alright. That's clear. So when running the first variant 1000 times I should at least see the correct result a couple of times (I know, I know, this is not guaranteed but the chance approaches 1)?

Comment: @harm: Maybe. Timing issues are very difficult to work with and doubly so in the console. Changing your server code to sleep for a second or two before returning the JSON should give you more predictable results.